# What constitutes active participation in the beta for the [beta] badge?

Tags: support

What constitutes active participation in the private beta for the [beta] badge?  The current description is quite vague.

Comment: This would probably get a better answer at [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

2 questions, 3 answers, and 1 vote appears to be sufficient, since I just got a beta badge on gadgets.stackexchange.